# What is The Memory Address of Character Table In DOS?

Tags: c, memory, assembly, dos, vga

What is the address of character table in DOS where we can create new fonts and symbols by manipulating the pixels of the each character?

I know to change it with BIOS interrupts, but I only need the memory address of the character table in dos for direct access.

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't find the close reason for "Asked 20 years too late"

Comment: This has nothing to do with DOS but with the VGA hardware. Search for "vga character generator" or similar and you will probably find information. If I remember correctly it might require port IO rather than memory-mapped IO.

Comment: One very important question: is this in normal text-mode or is it in `AX=13h` mode (i.e. the 320x200 graphics mode with 256 colors) ?

Comment: How is this "not a real question"?

Comment: Voted to reopen. It may be about "obsolete" technology but it's clearly about a programming problem.

Comment: Can we reopen this question? It's pretty silly that I 100% understand the question, came here from a google search where I was trying to find the answer to this question AND there is a well researched ANSWER.

Answer (score 9):

I can't remember how it was done any more (I did this stuff two decades ago), but you might want to look at the [FreeVGA project](http://www.osdever.net/FreeVGA/home.htm). According to the [text mode documentation](http://www.osdever.net/FreeVGA/vga/vgatext.htm#fonts) you can [select the address](http://www.osdever.net/FreeVGA/vga/seqreg.htm#03) yourself (kinda; see the Character Map Select Register). Accessing that register is [explained here](http://www.osdever.net/FreeVGA/vga/vgareg.htm).

You might also want to look at [this presentation](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/54271018/VGA-Text-Mode) which deals with this topic as well (and is probably easier to comprehend).

**Edit:** [Here's a post that explains how to replace a single character](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/x86_asm/190855/191477/re-how-do-i-change-font-with-bios-interrupts/?S=B10000&ReadPostMode=1). He uses [int 10h, ax=1100h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0136.htm) ([alternative documentation](http://www.ousob.com/ng/asm/ng7574c.php)) to exchange a character, but in the CX register you can actually tell how many characters should be exchanged. [Here's a very comprehensive list of `int 10h` functions](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm).

**Edit 2:** Found [another nice documentation](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0091.HTM).

**Edit 3:** In the last linked documentation, there's this:

> Programming for Direct Access to Character Generator RAM
>
> The following sequence sets up the EGA and VGA for accessing character-
>     generator memory.  See EGA I/O Ports for related information.

```
out 3c4H, 0402H   Mask reg; enable write to map 2
out 3c4H, 0704H   Memory Mode reg ; alpha, ext mem, non-interleaved
out 3ceH, 0005H   Graphics Mode reg; non-interleaved access
out 3ceH, 0406H   Graphics Misc reg; map char gen RAM to a000:0
out 3ceH, 0204H   Graphics ReadMapSelect reg; enable read chargen RAM
```

> After these OUTs, the font data begins at a000:0 and the first byte of
>     font data for a character begins at the character's ASCII value * 32.
>     After reading or writing the font data, the following sequence restores
>     the EGA/VGA to normal operations:

```
out 3c4H, 0302H   Mask reg; disable write to map 2
out 3c4H, 0304H   Memory Mode reg; alpha, ext mem, interleaved
out 3ceH, 1005H   Graphics Mode reg; interleaved access
out 3ceH, 0e06H   Graphics Misc reg; regen buffer to b800:0
out 3ceH, 0004H   Graphics ReadMapSelect reg; disable read chargen RAM
```

Comment: int 10h is the BIOS interrupt vector.  He explicitly stated he didn't want to go that route for some reason.

Comment: @JUST MY correct OPINION: Right, missed that. The last document has a description on how to do it with DMA, have quoted it.

Comment: There.  That crossed the barrier into +1 territory.  :D

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly and the graphic cards didn't change too much (I played with that the last time more than 15 years ago), the font information isn't at a given memory address, it is loaded on the graphic card memory.

Comment: If _I_ remember correctly (I too haven't used it for more than a decade), it is on the graphics card, but it's mapped to a memory address.

Comment: It's both. It's in ROM on the graphics card, but it could be changed too somehow.