# Print Unicode Characters in 8086

Tags: unicode, x86-16

As you know, the print function in 8086, puts character in 8bits ( db ) and shows it in screen. Now, i want to print the `Unicode` character in `8086emu` environment not `ASCII`. So, my challenge is how to use Unicode character in my program ? Does 8086 support Unicode characters?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean printing in text mode, via interrupt 10h: you can't, as you only have a character map with just 256 characters available. You can [redefine how these characters look like (load your custom font)](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0151.HTM), but that still gives you only 256 characters. So you would need to identify the ones you need and then first somehow "render" the ones you need into the character table and for printing you would need to map the Unicode glyph to you character table indexes.

See also [my answer to a similar question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178423/400056).