# How can I use Unicode in Turbo C++?

Tags: c++, unicode, subscript, turbo-c++, superscript

How can I use Unicode symbols in Turbo C++?

I particularly want to superscript and subscript symbols.

I must use the outdated Turbo C++ as this is what my school provides and I have to use this for my project.

Comment: You mostly can't. "Turbo C++" was invented back when dinosaurs roamed the Earth, and Unicode, as we know it, was rarely known.

Comment: For e.g. UTF-8 you can handle it as arrays of bytes, and you have to implement *everything* else yourself.

Comment: SO users need to complete their profile so we can tell where they come from.  DOS emulators do not have the plumbing to accurately render sub/superscript text.  You can get a bit of superscript, [look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850#Character_set) for example.  Just keep in mind that your teacher doesn't expect you to do this.

Comment: If you must use Turbo C++ then you should not be required to use Unicode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a simple "Hello World"-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)

Comment: Text mode in DOS can only read from a table of 256 characters, but that character set can be changed to add custom bitmaps. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178276/what-is-the-memory-address-of-character-table-in-dos/6178423#6178423

Comment: Turbo C++ isn't even a C++ compiler, as it predates the first C++ standard in 1998 for almost a decade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, Turbo C++ won't get you any straight access to Unicode. It is likely that it is so old that it can't even generate code that could be made to use the system's libraries (DLL), so - even by recreating header files by hand, you could not call `wprintf` which could output proper Unicode even on the arcane `cmd` terminal Microsoft ships with Windows to this day.

However, the default character encoding used in the cmd terminal supports some non-ASCII characters - which exactly will depend on the language (locale) configuration of your OS. (For example, for Western European languages, it is usually ["cp-852"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852) - although it can be [CP 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), if your Windows is in English.

None of these legacy 8-bit character map encodings will include all ten digits as super-script - but you might have some available (CP 850 features "¹,²,³", for example).

So, you could check the terminal code page, and check on Wikipedia for their codes - you can inspect and change the current code page with the `chcp` command in the Windows terminal. If your Windows version supports [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which covers all printable Unicode characters, you have to type `chcp 65001` in the terminal. (I don't know which Windows editions support that, nor which you are using.)

Once you manage to do that, all you need is to print the byte-sequences for the super-script digits in UTF-8, using the "\xHH" encoding for characters in a string (I am not sure if Turbo C++ will allow it. Otherwise, `printf ("%c%c", 0xHH, 0xHH) will work.)

For your convenience, I am attaching the codepoints and UTF-8 encodings for superscripts:

```
0x00B2: SUPERSCRIPT TWO - ² - utf-8 seq: b'\xc2\xb2'
0x00B3: SUPERSCRIPT THREE - ³ - utf-8 seq: b'\xc2\xb3'
0x00B9: SUPERSCRIPT ONE - ¹ - utf-8 seq: b'\xc2\xb9'
0x0670: ARABIC LETTER SUPERSCRIPT ALEF - ٰ - utf-8 seq: b'\xd9\xb0'
0x0711: SYRIAC LETTER SUPERSCRIPT ALAPH - ܑ - utf-8 seq: b'\xdc\x91'
0x2070: SUPERSCRIPT ZERO - ⁰ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xb0'
0x2071: SUPERSCRIPT LATIN SMALL LETTER I - ⁱ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xb1'
0x2074: SUPERSCRIPT FOUR - ⁴ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xb4'
0x2075: SUPERSCRIPT FIVE - ⁵ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xb5'
0x2076: SUPERSCRIPT SIX - ⁶ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xb6'
0x2077: SUPERSCRIPT SEVEN - ⁷ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xb7'
0x2078: SUPERSCRIPT EIGHT - ⁸ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xb8'
0x2079: SUPERSCRIPT NINE - ⁹ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xb9'
0x207A: SUPERSCRIPT PLUS SIGN - ⁺ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xba'
0x207B: SUPERSCRIPT MINUS - ⁻ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xbb'
0x207C: SUPERSCRIPT EQUALS SIGN - ⁼ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xbc'
0x207D: SUPERSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS - ⁽ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xbd'
0x207E: SUPERSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS - ⁾ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xbe'
0x207F: SUPERSCRIPT LATIN SMALL LETTER N - ⁿ - utf-8 seq: b'\xe2\x81\xbf'
0xFC5B: ARABIC LIGATURE THAL WITH SUPERSCRIPT ALEF ISOLATED FORM - ﱛ - utf-8 seq: b'\xef\xb1\x9b'
0xFC5C: ARABIC LIGATURE REH WITH SUPERSCRIPT ALEF ISOLATED FORM - ﱜ - utf-8 seq: b'\xef\xb1\x9c'
0xFC5D: ARABIC LIGATURE ALEF MAKSURA WITH SUPERSCRIPT ALEF ISOLATED FORM - ﱝ - utf-8 seq: b'\xef\xb1\x9d'
0xFC63: ARABIC LIGATURE SHADDA WITH SUPERSCRIPT ALEF ISOLATED FORM - ﱣ - utf-8 seq: b'\xef\xb1\xa3'
0xFC90: ARABIC LIGATURE ALEF MAKSURA WITH SUPERSCRIPT ALEF FINAL FORM - ﲐ - utf-8 seq: b'\xef\xb2\x90'
0xFCD9: ARABIC LIGATURE HEH WITH SUPERSCRIPT ALEF INITIAL FORM - ﳙ - utf-8 seq: b'\xef\xb3\x99'
```

(This was generated with the following Python snippet in interactive mode:)

```py
import unicodedata
for i in range(0, 0x10ffff):
    char = chr(i)
    try:
        name = unicodedata.name(char)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    if "SUPERSCRIPT" not in name:
        continue
    print(f"0x{i:04X}: {name} - {char} - utf-8 seq: {char.encode('utf-8')}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Old **Turbo C++** (not the BDS2006 Turbo C++) is for **MS-DOS** 16-bit targets, so it does not support [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) at all, nor TTF fonts, etc. So in order to get Unicode to work, you have two options:

1. **Implement Unicode on your own**

   So you need to render Unicode text. In graphics mode it is simple. Just use a "complete" Unicode font, like:

   - [GNU_Unifont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Unifont)

   IIRC It's raster so it's easy to decode and render (you can even create a big bitmap from it in a newer OS and use that in MS-DOS as a font). For rendering in graphics mode, you can use direct pixel access (VGA/VESA). In text modes it's much harder as you need to update the EGA/VGA font with the characters you are actually using. But the count of distinct actually rendered characters on screen is limited to 256 per font. For more information, see:

   - [Graphics rendering in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660815/display-an-array-of-color-in-c/21699076#21699076)

   Of course, supporting the whole Unicode is a problem under MS-DOS as the full font even in small resolution is usually 12-64  MB big so you need to have enough **XMS memory** (as you do not fit 640 KB nor 1 MB model any more) and implement fast paging/access to used characters in order to be usable fast... Another option is to use 32-bit protected mode where you got 32-bit linear memory access (but then you have no more MS-DOS support and need to do all the OS stuff on your own, but extenders like DOS4GW can do some of it for you...)

   You could use one shortcut avoiding memory management. You could create a [RAM disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk) and store your raw font image as file in the RAM disk. File access to it should be fast (well faster than accessing the HDD) ... so at appplication start, copy the font from the HDD into the RAM disk location and then just use that... thanks to this, XMS is not needed any more.
2. **Transform Unicode strings into extended ASCII**

   With characters supporting your special characters outside the standard ASCII table. There are MS-DOS utilities for this (supporting latin1, 2, kamenicky,...) which provide the extended font and keyboard handling (within selected codepage).

   So you would need to have a conversion table for all characters you want to support and map between UTF-8, UTF-16 and your ASCII + extended characters. However, this way it can support only 128 extended characters.